# Get-EventLog not parsing Message when run by SYSTEM user

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-eventlog, get-winevent

## Problem

I am trying to schedule a job that monitors events on remote machines.

I wrote the script based on the `Get-EventLog` command and it works properly when run by my account. But when I run the `Get-EventLog` as `SYSTEM` user, the `.Message` attribute of the returned objects shows the following error:

> The description for Event ID '4724' in Source 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event: {somedata}

When I use the `Get-WinEvent` command as `SYSTEM` user, the problem does not appear and the `.Message` part displays properly.

I would stick with `Get-WinEvent`, especially since the data is much easier to parse (thanks to the `ToXML()` method), but the `Get-EventLog` happens to be terribly faster :(

## Question

Does anyone have any idea why the `Get-EventLog` fails to render `.Message` when run by `SYSTEM` user and perhaps how to fix it?

To avoid obvious answers:

- the `COMPUTER$` account is member of `DOMAIN\Event Log Readers` group,
- the `COMPUTER$` account does have the read privileges over the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security` on remote machines,
- obviously, the registry entries for `Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing` and related DLL's are identical on both the source and target computers.

Comment: Since you are using `get-winevent` can you try passing -credential parameter

Comment: This seems related https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/04/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-query-event-logs-to-discover-active-directory-information/

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Get-WinEvent -LogName “Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing” | where ID -eq  4724 | select-object -ExpandProperty Message

Comment: As I have already explained, I do know that ``Get-WinEvent`` works. But it's terribly slow compared to ``Get-Eventlog`` and thus the question is specifically about the latter.